# How to get go to working at bottom of Microsoft Word doc

Tags: microsoft-word

I  have been using The "go to" function at the bottom of the microsoft word page but suddenly it has disappeared.  How do I get the GO TO function to work?

Comment: can't find what you've said . I have microsoft 2011 for Mac

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a newer version of Office, go to the "Home" tab, on the right hand side you should see a drop down menu called "Find".

If you click that menu, you can right click on "go to" and add it to the "Quick Access Toolbar".  It's not at the bottom of the page, but at the top, above the tabs.

Also "Control-G" is also something you can use if you don't mind using a keyboard shortcut.